# Wordpress: Modifying the content function

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

is there a way to modify the the_content() function? I would like to add a css class when it display a custom taxonomy negative and positive taxonomy.

Example:

```
<p class="positive">this is a content for the positive taxonomy</p>
<p class="positive">this is a content for the positive taxonomy</p>
<p class="negative">this is a content for the negative taxonomy</p>
```

I would like to apply it in the *author.php* code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

with the *function.php* :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_author() ) {

        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'custom_feedback' );

    }

});
```

**PS:** I am using custom post type here with custom taxonomy with two category positive and negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) to test whether or not a post has a certain term. Alternatvely, you can use `get_the_terms` to get the terms attached to a post and use the term slug as value in your css class. This is a bit unreliable if  a post has more than one term attached to it

### SOLUTION 1

```
<?php
    $class = '';
    if ( has_term( 'positive', 'custom_taxonomy' ) ) {
        $class = 'positive';
    } elseif ( has_term( 'negative', 'custom_taxonomy' ) ) {
        $class = 'negative';
    } 
?>

<div class="entry-content ><?php echo $class ?>">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

### SOLUTION 2

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy' );
$class = $terms ? $terms[0]->slug : 'normal';
?>

<div class="entry-content ><?php echo $class ?>">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

### USAGE

You can now use your CSS selectors to target your content

```
.entry-content positive {}
.entry-content negative {}
```

Comment: wow..so amazing! the code is not that long but it works. you are genius bro. thanks much. salute!!

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)